# Is the accuracy or PDOP included in smartphone or GPS camera?

Tags: geolocation, accuracy

I would like to properly geolocate picture Exifs on a smartphone or GPS camera and would like to record the accuracy of the GPS position as well.

I have downloaded a few photos from camera review sites and with this short survey I could only find one camera listing the [number of satellites](http://www.opanda.com/en/pe/help/gps.html#GPSSatellites).

Any ideas?

Here are the geolocation attributes from my low-end smartphone:

```
GPSVersionID    2.2.0.0
GPSLatitudeRef  South
GPSLongitudeRef East
GPSAltitudeRef  Above Sea Level
GPSTimeStamp    12:39:37
GPSProcessingMethod GPS
GPSDateStamp    2019:02:01


GPSAltitude 180.4 m Above Sea Level
GPSDateTime 2019:02:01 12:39:37Z
GPSLatitude 32 deg 52' 56.39" S
GPSLongitude    18 deg 38' 32.81" E
GPSPosition (-32.882330556,18.642725000)
            32 deg 52' 56.39" S, 18 deg 38' 33.81" E
```

Comment: I have not used this tool, but this ExifTool looks promising: https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/geotag.html

Comment: @RichardMorgan it is an excellent tool for standard data. It is important to read the full content of the `MakerNotes` tag, as ExifTool can report it as being garbage while it indeed contains valuable non-standard information

Comment: @JGH The question is about the automatic generation of the correct exif fields by the camera or smartphone.